# Best way to vectorize appending mis-matched rows into pandas dataframe from list

Tags: python, pandas

looking for assistance in speeding up this operation. I am trying to insert list elements as rows into a `pandas` `df` where the number of list elements can be less than (but will never exceed) the number of columns.

I am currently doing this in a loop, and that takes a very long time at scale. Any ideas as to how I can vectorize this operation, or atleast improve speed? I am pretty new to python & would appreciate any help I can get!

```
import pandas as pd

myList = ['a/b/c','a/b','a','a/b/c']

def split_contents(x):
  return x.split('/')

split_list = list(map(split_contents, myList))  

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) 

#very slow performance at scale - way to vectorize/speed up?
for i in range(0, len(split_list)):
  df = df.append(pd.Series(split_list[i], index=df.columns[:len(split_list[i])]), ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Note: Using Python 3.8.8

Thank you!

Comment: you need to fill in one time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier and more efficient way to do that with Pandas [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

myList = ["a/b/c", "a/b", "a", "a/b/c"]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [x.split("/") for x in myList], columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"]
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     b     c
1    a     b  None
2    a  None  None
3    a     b     c
```